# How to define parent/child relationship using Nest FluentAPI, while Mappings is deprecated?

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, nest

I would like to create Parent-Child Mapping using FluentAPI. There is no example, how to do it on documentation. Only one example, that I have found is https://discuss.elastic.co/t/help-with-nest-fluentapi-create-parent-child-mapping-on-existing-index/90248 . But deprecated *Mappings* is used here. How to do it now, without deprecated *Mappings*, using FluentAPI, instead of *AutoMap()*?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Parent/Child relationships documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/parent-child-relationships.html). There's an example that walks through mapping and indexing documents.

Here's an example

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "my_index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var createIndexResponse = client.Indices.Create(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Map<MyDocument>(m => m
            .RoutingField(r => r.Required())
            // map properties of parent document
            .Properties<MyParent>(p => p
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(n => n.ParentProperty)
                )
            )
            // map properties of child document
            .Properties<MyChild>(p => p
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(n => n.ChildProperty)
                )
            )
            // map properties of base document
            .Properties(p => p
                .Join(j => j
                    .Name(p => p.MyJoinField)
                    .Relations(r => r
                        .Join<MyParent, MyChild>()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
}

public abstract class MyDocument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JoinField MyJoinField { get; set; }
}

public class MyParent : MyDocument
{
    public string ParentProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyChild : MyDocument
{
    public string ChildProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen this documentation. The problem is that I need to use FluentApi, instead of attributes mapping, as it is done in the documentation. It could be done before, using Mappings, but now it is deprecated.

Comment: The example uses attributes on a couple of properties and automaps, but the call is made with the fluent API

Comment: I also want to configure MyParent and MyChild mappings using FluentApi. Like add multifields for their properties and other things.

Comment: There can be only one mapping in an index in Elasticsearch 7.x. With parent/child relationships, the parent documents and child documents share the one mapping, with a `"join"` field identifying the relationship between parent and children. When it comes to C# POCOs, the example shown above maps properties from `MyParent` and `MyChild` to the one mapping. On this mapping you can also add multi-fields, dynamic templates, etc.